# Is there a way to make the tappable area for the UIBarButtonItem as 44x44?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Based on the HIG the size of the button that is tappable should be 44x44. Now I have the following:

```
UIButton * stop = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [stop setSize:CGSizeMake(15, 18)];


    [stop setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop-gray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [stop addTarget:self action:@selector(stopPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    stopButton_ = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:stop];
```

The UIBarButtonItem will be put inside a UIToolbar for the iphone. As you notice the size of the image there is smaller than 15, 18. Is there a way to make the tappable area for the UIBarButtonItem as 44x44? Or do I have to create a new icon which has an empty space so that the size is 44x44, what is the best practice for this in the iOS world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a custom view? If you just want a custom image on the button, use `-[UIBarButtonItem initWithImage:style:target:action:]` and you'll get the correct tappable area and standard system behaviors.

If there's something you actually need the custom view for, you shouldn't need to change your image to leave empty space... just set the `contentHorizontalAlignment` and `contentVerticalAlignment` so that the image is centered instead of filling the view, then size your view however you want.

Comment: well the issue is that my image color is gray and when I do that the back is white

Comment: Your question started with a HIG recommendation... the HIG [also says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW8) toolbar icons should be white. If you're graying out the icon to indicate it can't be used right now, why not use the `enabled` property on UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: it's a custom gray that I have for it

Comment: and also it's not used because it's disabled.. it just can't be used

Answer (score 0):

I think an Image 44x44 with transparent Backgroud and the smaller image inside woud be the easyest way.

Comment: @rickster: why do you think alignments are better?

Comment: It's not necessarily better -- mainly I pointed it out because the OP asked if you *have to* create a larger image with empty space or if there's another way. There's at least one argument in favor of using alignments, though: a large image filled with transparent image is a (probably trivially) larger file.